# Print line of a txt file in python create break line when print

Tags: python

i'm new to python and i'm trying read every line of a simple txt file, but when print out the result in the terminal, between every line there is an empty line that in the txt file doesn't exist and i have use strip() method to avoid that line, this is the code:

```
ins = open( "abc.txt", "r" )
array = []
for line in ins:
    array.append( line )
ins.close()

for riga in array:
    if line.strip() != '':
        print riga
```

this is the txt file:

```
a
b
c
```

and this is the result in the terminal:

```
a

b

c
```

i can't understand why create that empty line between a,b,c, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be:

```
for riga in array:
    if line.strip() != '':
        print riga
```

This:

```
for riga in array:
    if riga.strip() != '':     # <= riga here not line 
        print riga.strip()     # Print add a new line so strip the stored \n
```

Or better yet:

```
array = []
with open("abc.txt") as ins:
    for line in ins
        array.append(line.strip())

for line in array:
    if line:
        print line
```

Answer (score 3):

Because everything in a text file is a character, so when you see something like:

```
a
b
c
```

Its *actually* `a\nb\nc\n`, `\n` means new line, and this is the reason why you're getting that extra space. If you'd like to print everything in the text file into the output console just the way it is, I would fix your `print` statement like so:

```
print riga,
```

This prevents the addition of an *extra* new line character, `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `line.strip() != ''`, I don't think this is doing what you expect.

- It calls the `strip()` string method on `line` which will be the last line of the file since you have already iterated over all of the `line`s in the previous `for` loop, leaving the `line` variable assigned  to the last one.
- It then checks if the returned stripped string from `line` is not equal to `''`.
- If that condition is met, it prints `riga`.

You need to run `strip()` on the string you want to print then either store the result or print it right away, and why not do it all in one `for` loop like this:

```
array = []
with open("abc.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
       array.append(line.strip())
       print(array[-1])
```